# Canvas Width and Height from form values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this code, the canvas height and width take values from nCol and nLin values at first time, but doesn't update when the values of nCol and nLin values change.
Where you should locate the code for the change is dynamic? inside if (canvas.getContext) {} or in the function MakeCnv?

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas">
    <span style="color: red">
    <b>canvas</b> not supported</span>
</canvas>
<br />
Col: <input type="text" value="3" id="nCol" />
Lin: <input type="text" value="3" id="nLin" />
Text: <input type="text" value="Text" id="texto" />
<input type="button" value="Make Canvas"
onclick="MakeCnv()" />

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var line = document.getElementById("nLin").value;
var cols = document.getElementById("nCol").value;
var cnv = null;

// resize the canvas
canvas.width = line * 32;
canvas.height = cols * 32;
canvas.style="border: blue solid 1px";

if (canvas.getContext) {
    cnv = canvas.getContext("2d");
    MakeCnv();
}
function MakeCnv(){
        cnv.strokeStyle = "olive";
        // put the text in the canvas
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` attribute. Add it either to your inputs:

```
<input onchange="run()">
```

Or use it in your JS:

```
document.getElementById("nLin").onchange = run();
```

Both require the function `run` to be defined - all this has to contain is the variable settings:

```
var line,
    cols;

function run() {
    line = document.getElementById("nLin").value;
    cols = document.getElementById("nCol").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<script>` block to add a new function that handles the canvas size:

```
<script>
function resizeCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var line = document.getElementById("nLin").value;
    var cols = document.getElementById("nCol").value;

    // resize the canvas
    canvas.width = line * 32;
    canvas.height = cols * 32;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.style="border: blue solid 1px";
resizeCanvas();

var cnv = null;
if (canvas.getContext) {
    cnv = canvas.getContext("2d");
    MakeCnv();
}

function MakeCnv(){
    cnv.strokeStyle = "olive";
    // put the text in the canvas
}
</script>
```

Change your `<input>` text boxes to attach an `onchange` event listener.

```
Col: <input type="text" value="3" id="nCol" onchange="resizeCanvas()"/>
Lin: <input type="text" value="3" id="nLin" onchange="resizeCanvas()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`canvas.style="border: blue solid 1px";`
you probably want
`canvas.style.border = "blue solid 1px";`

Your code could be changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
function dimensionCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var line   = document.getElementById("nLin").value;
    var cols   = document.getElementById("nCol").value;
    window.cnv = null;  
    // resize the canvas also clears the canvas as per spec!!!
    canvas.width = line * 32; 
    canvas.height = cols * 32; 
    canvas.style.border = "blue solid 1px"; 
    if (canvas.getContext) { 
      window.cnv = canvas.getContext("2d");
      MakeCnv();
    }
}

function MakeCnv(){
        cnv.strokeStyle = "olive";
        // put the text in the canvas
}

window.onload=function(){
    dimensionCanvas();
};
//]]>  
</script>
</head><body>
<canvas id="canvas">
    <span style="color: red">
    <b>canvas</b> not supported</span>
</canvas>
<br />
Col: <input type="text" value="3" id="nCol" onchange="dimensionCanvas()" />
Lin: <input type="text" value="3" id="nLin" onchange="dimensionCanvas()" />
Text: <input type="text" value="Text" id="texto" />
<input type="button" value="Make Canvas" onclick="MakeCnv()" />
</body></html>
```

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FKV94/).